# Java create ArrayList of objects on run time with a specific name

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to build an ArrayList of objects in runtime inside a method with a specific name:

```
public void createNewArray(String arrayName){

    ArrayList <StoreItem> arrayName = new ArrayList<StoreItem>();
}
```

The reason I'm trying is because, I don't know how many ArrayLists I will need to create.

What I'm trying to do is to pass a string parameter to the function (`createNewArray`) and then use this parameter as the ArrayList name.

Can I do such thing in Java?

Comment: No. If you don't know how many lists you'll have, then create a list of lists (or any other more appropriate collection of lists, depending on your use-case).

Comment: You're probably looking for a `Map` instead of a `List`. See [HashMap<K,V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Using  a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<StoreItem>>` would allow you to store the lists "by name".

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap:

```
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();        
    }

    public static void createNewArray(String arrayName){
        // Create your array list here
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        map.put(arrayName, list);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how many ArrayLists I will need to create.

What about using an array list of array lists? Those things exist you know.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<StoreItem>> myLists = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you can use it just like a normal array list:

```
myLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
myLists.get(0).add(new StoreItem());
// ...
```

Alternatively, if you want to access one of your lists with a string, you can try a hash map of array lists:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<StoreItem>> myLists = new HashMap<>();
```

And you can just use it like a normal hash map:

```
myLists.put("foo", new ArrayList<>());
myLists.get("foo").add(new StoreItem());
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a `HashMap` of `ArrayList`?

```
public class MyArrays <T> {

     protected HashMap<String, ArrayList<T>> arrays = new HashMap<>();

     public void createNewArray(String arrayName) {
         arrays.put(arrayName, new ArrayList<T>());
     }

     public ArrayList<T> getArray(String arrayName) {
         return arrays.get(arrayName);
     }

}
```

You can simply use it that way:

```
MyArrays<StoredItem> arr = new MyArrays<>();
arr.createNewArray("first");
...
ArrayList<StoredItem> first = arr.getArray("first");
```